# Proof of the proposition which says that the column rank of $A$ is equal to the row rank of $A$. (Gilbert Strang's new lecture)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, matrix-rank

I am watching [this new lecture](https://youtu.be/YiqIkSHSmyc?t=1760) by Gilbert Strang.

I have the following question.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\3&1&4\\5&7&12\\\end{bmatrix}$.

Prof. Strang showed that the column rank of $A$ is equal to the row rank of $A$.

His proof is like the following:

Because $$\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\12\end{bmatrix} = 1 \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\5\end{bmatrix}+ 1 \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\7\end{bmatrix},$$
the column rank of $A$ is $2$ and
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\3&1&4\\5&7&12\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\\5&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then he says that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are the basis of the row space of $A$ because $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are linearly independent and each of the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}5\\7\\12\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear combination of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

**Don't we need to show that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are in the row space of $A$?**

For example, $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\3&1&4\\5&7&12\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\3&1&4\\5&7&12\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are linearly independent and each of the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}5\\7\\12\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear combination of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$. But $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are not the basis of the row space of $A$.

$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ generate $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is bigger than the row space of $A$.

Comment: Maybe, but that's easy, almost obvious. The first is the 2nd row minus the 1st row, the other is what you get when you add the first two rows, subtract that from the 3rd row, and divide by 5.

Comment: If $A$ is a general $m \times n$ matrix, is it also easy?

Answer (score 1):

We have $A=C R$ as in the lecture. the row space of $A$ is the column space of $A^T$ and $A^T=R^T C^T$ so the colums space of $A^T$ is generated by the columns of $C^T$ (using coefficients from $R^T$) and those columns are just the rows of $C$ again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the columns of $R^T$ generate the column space of $A^T$. Then, the rows of $R$ generates the row space of $A$. And the rows of $R$ are linearly independent as in the lecture. Are the rows of $R$ in the row space of $A$? This is my question.